# Dynamic data doesn't work inside angular drawer

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I'm trying to include select with data loaded from the json inside drawer. I use snap plugin. It works with hardcoded data but it doesn't work when i use dynamic data:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.0-rc1" data-semver="1.2.0-rc1" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0rc1/angular.js"></script>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/angular-snap.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.0-rc1" data-semver="1.2.0-rc1" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0rc1/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="js/snap.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-snap.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <snap-drawer>
      <p ng-controller="RandCtrl">
        Here's a big random number to show the drawer content 
        does not reload:                         <span>{{rand}}</span>
      </p>
        <select ng-model="correctlySelected"
                ng-options="opt as opt.label for opt in options">
            </select>
    </snap-drawer>
    <snap-content id="content">
      <ng-view>aaaa</ng-view>
    </snap-content>
  </body>

</html>
```

This is my controller:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['snap']);

app.controller('RandCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000);

   $scope.options = [
    { label: 'one', value: 1 },
    { label: 'two', value: 2 }
  ];

  $scope.correctlySelected = $scope.options[1];
});
```

Comment: and where is your controller?

Comment: The controller is attached

Comment: your controller not attached correctly  <p>  not closed include rest of contoller

Comment: @TuviaKhusid I copied your code to my local, and it is showing the random value, and drawer seems to work as well

Comment: i need the dropdown working. The select doesn't work

Comment: show my answer in plunker

Comment: @TuviaKhusid was the problem something different than my answer?

Answer (score 0):

ng-controller="RandCtrl"   // put in body     or in all code

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mMIZQtU73RjccbDDO9Dp?p=preview)    `<body ng-controller="RandCtrl">`